# Store values from JSON output retrieved from SPARQL endpoint in a array

Tags: angularjs, sparql

Here is the working code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $http({
    url: 'http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/landregistry/query', 
    headers: { 'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept' : 'application/sparql-results+json' },
    method: "GET",
    params: {
            query : "select * where {?s a ?o} limit 10",
            format: "json"
        }
  })

  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.results = data.results.bindings;
    // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available 
   })

  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
  });

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LfkIPZRsZ4QHTfq2A2vc?p=preview

My doubt is how to store for instance, all s.values in an array such that the array can be further used to populate a drop down menu without having to save the JSON output to an external file.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it simple JSON processing in Javascript? And why do you think you have to "save the JSON ouptut to an external file"? Parsing the JSON will return a JSON object

Comment: Okay, thanks, well, because I didn't know about JSON processing in Javascript. Can you show code example?

Comment: var json = JSON.parse($scope.results);

Added this to html:
{{json.value}}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

You are already storing the results as a list in `$scope.results`.

To use the values for `s` in a dropdown menu, for example, you can do this:

`<select ng-options="item as item.s.value for item in results" ng-model="selected"></select>`

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/bPQknJsq0LogSvotNH1r?p=preview)